# Sequelize multi table association query with ORs

Tags: javascript, sql-server, sequelize.js

I have to find a field in different tables, that is, I have to check if the search is in different fields of the Customer table, in different fields of the Shops table, and in different fields of the ContactPerson table

The Customer and Persons and Customer Shops tables are 1-N and are associated

My "search" variable is what I wanna find.

This is my code

```
CustomerPersonsRelation()
CustomerShop()
    var result = await CustomerModel.findAll({
        ...params,
        include: [
            {model : ShopModel},
            {model: ContactPersonModel}
        ]
    })
```

All is imported don't worry about that.
My Params are these:

```
{
        where: {
            $or: [
                {
                    '$Customer.customer_name$': { $like: '%' + search + '%' },
                },
                {
                    '$Customer.customer_fiscal_name$': { $like: '%' + search + '%' },
                },
                {
                    '$Customer.customer_responsable_name$': { $like: '%' + search + '%' },
                },
                {
                    '$Customer.customer_responsable_phone$': { $like: '%' + search + '%' },
                },
                {
                    '$Customer.customer_web$': { $like: '%' + search + '%' },
                },
                {
                    '$Shops.shop_name$': { $like: '%' + search + '%' },
                },
                {
                    '$Shops.shop_phone$': { $like: '%' + search + '%' },
                },
                {
                    '$Shops.shop_mobile$': { $like: '%' + search + '%' },
                },
                {
                    '$ContactPersons.contactp_name$': { $like: '%' + search + '%' },
                },
                {
                    '$ContactPersons.contactp_phone$': { $like: '%' + search + '%' },
                },
                {
                    '$ContactPersons.contactp_mobile$': { $like: '%' + search + '%' },
                }
            ]
        },
        limit: 3
    })
}
```

But that returns this error:
Error : SequelizeDatabaseError: The multi-part identifier "ContactPersons.contactp_mobile" could not be bound. (And this error for all related fields.)

What I can do for that works?

Comment: This is because the left join is out the where. How i can put it inner?

Comment: There is an issue with LIMIT, all works well without limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!

After a lot of tests i discovered the error was not in relation and was not in the OR, was in the LIMIT.

After search i solved this adding `duplicating: false` in includes.

The final code is this:

```
    var result = await CustomerModel.findAll({
        include: [
            {model : ShopModel, require: true, duplicating: false},
            {model: ContactPersonModel, require: true, duplicating: false}
        ],
        ...params,
        raw
    })
```

Comment: Just had this problem when using `findOne()` in Sequelize v6. It looks like Sequelize tries to turn every relation into a sub-select to make sure OFFSET/LIMIT is added to each relation (a.k.a. "duplicating").